# "A problem with option reference". Problems with Basic Calculator code

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python. I can't find out what really is the problem here. I am coding a basic calculator that asks for two inputs; 'firstnum' and 'secondnum'. Then, a numbered options list is outputted. The user then picks one number from 1-4. Based on that and the inputs, a calculation is performed. After that, I want to ask the user if they want to continue with further operation (loop) but that is when the loop is broken. So, I want the code to go back to the while loop after it has broken. So, if 6 is pressed it will go back to the while loop. If 7, exit code.

```
print("Hello, welcome to my calculator")
firstnum = int(input("Enter your first number"))
secondnum = int(input("Enter your second number"))
def loop(

        while True:
                Options = int(input('''
                       1 is Addition
                       2 is Subtraction
                       3 is Multiplication
                       4 is Division
        
                           '''))
                if Options ==1:
                        print("The total is", firstnum + secondnum)
                elif Options ==2:
                        print("The total is", firstnum - secondnum)
                elif Options ==3:
                        print("The total is", firstnum*secondnum)
                elif Options ==4:
                        print("The total is", firstnum/secondnum)

                break

print("Would you like to continue?")
ask = int(input('''
        6 for Yes
        7 for No
                '''))
if ask ==6:
                continue

elif ask ==7:
        exit
```

Comment: You're missing the parameter list on the `def loop` line.

Comment: Please use 4 spaces consistently as your indentation.

Comment: You also never call the `loop()` function.

Comment: Let us know what went wrong. When I run it, I get a SyntaxError. If that's what you see, say so - and include the traceback message so that the information here in the quetion. And, `exit` is a function. You'll need to do `exit()` (or include an exit code e.g., `exit(2)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`continue` only works inside the `while` loop, so try moving it back in there:

```
print("Hello, welcome to my calculator")
firstnum = int(input("Enter your first number"))
secondnum = int(input("Enter your second number"))


while True:
    Options = int(input('''
                       1 is Addition
                       2 is Subtraction
                       3 is Multiplication
                       4 is Division

                           '''))
    if Options == 1:
        print("The total is", firstnum + secondnum)
    elif Options == 2:
        print("The total is", firstnum - secondnum)
    elif Options == 3:
        print("The total is", firstnum * secondnum)
    elif Options == 4:
        print("The total is", firstnum / secondnum)

    print("Would you like to continue?")
    ask = int(input('''
                                6 for Yes
                                7 for No
                                '''))
    if ask == 6:
        continue

    elif ask == 7:
        break

    else:
        raise ValueError(str(ask))
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped so much

Answer (score 0):

You never called the loop function nor the loop function syntax is correct,

Update the code like this,

```
print("Hello, welcome to my calculator")
firstnum = int(input("Enter your first number"))
secondnum = int(input("Enter your second number"))
value=True
while (value):
        opt = int(input('''
                       1 is Addition
                       2 is Subtraction
                       3 is Multiplication
                       4 is Division
        
                           '''))
        if opt ==1:
            print("The total is", firstnum + secondnum)
        elif opt ==2:
            print("The total is", firstnum - secondnum)
        elif opt ==3:
            print("The total is", firstnum*secondnum)
        elif opt ==4:
            print("The total is", firstnum/secondnum)
                   
        print("Would you like to continue?")
        ask = int(input('''6 for Yes 7 for No'''))
        if ask ==6:
            continue
        elif ask ==7:
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong Input! Shutting Down")
            break
```

`Value=true` is nothing but a true condition for the `while` loop to run infinitely based on inner conditions in your check blocks of `if` and `elif`

Dont use the break statement after `elif` use it in the exit condition (ask=7) to exit the loop and stop the program

Also Keep your indents in your code consistent.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for an explanation and an answer.